# Burninate [flight]

Tags: support, status-completed, burninate-tag

This month the very, very ambiguous tag [flight](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flight) was created, and is now being applied to <s>four</s> seven different unrelated topics (from GIS data to flight schools to trim to power curves). I request the tag be burninated, instead of bumping 4 (now 7) posts.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Personally, I agree to the burnination. I'll wait to see if there is any dissenting opinion

Comment: FYKA please, they're now seven.

Comment: wilco. thanks. Edited some, will finish later today

Comment: Isn't there a behind-the-scenes delete-tag? I would have thought it's better than bumping the posts, which was the purpose of the request here. Thanks anyways.

Comment: no, not for such small volumes. for large volumes an admin/CM can be summoned. the alternative is merging. Asking is still good, there might be opinions that have not been considered and need to be heard

Comment: Copy; thanks. I've now done the remaining two.

Answer (score 4):

We've blacklisted this to keep it from coming back. It's now considered an intrinsic tag.