# What should the [foreign] tag be used for?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just removed the [foreign](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/foreign) tag from [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/80769/how-do-i-determine-which-countries-have-mandated-tcas-ii-v7-1) because it seems unrelated to the question.

But I was wondering what the tag should be used for since it does not have any usage guidance. Right now there are **two questions** using it for flight experience / licences obtained abroad and how it relates to local regulations (in these cases FAA):

- [Do I need to keep my foreign based PPL after passing an FAA instrument checkride?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/70194/do-i-need-to-keep-my-foreign-based-ppl-after-passing-an-faa-instrument-checkride)
- [Do I have to prove my flight training time abroad when applying for a standalone FAA license?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/60574/do-i-have-to-prove-my-flight-training-time-abroad-when-applying-for-a-standalone)

There is **one question** using it for being a foreigner when getting a local licence:

- [Flight Training in US as an Alien](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/47647/flight-training-in-us-as-an-alien)
  (although this one is closed as a duplicate of [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/13579/can-foreign-pilots-get-an-faa-atpl-and-work-for-a-us-based-commercial-airline), which isn't tagged [foreign](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/foreign), but *incorrectly* uses [international](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/international), which is about international flights according to its guidance)

There is **one question** using it for getting an FAA licence while being abroad:

- [What are the requirements to obtain an FAA private pilot's license in Bosnia?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/30130/what-are-the-requirements-to-obtain-an-faa-private-pilots-license-in-bosnia)

There is **one question** using it for airlines operating an aircraft registered in a foreign country:

- [Which are the requirements to fly a N-registered aircraft operated by a non-US airline?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/29359/which-are-the-requirements-to-fly-a-n-registered-aircraft-operated-by-a-non-us-a)
  (closed as duplicate of [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/9375/can-a-non-us-citizen-or-entity-own-an-n-registered-aircraft), which also does not tag [foreign](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/foreign))

So what should this tag be used for? And do we even need it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So what should this tag be used for?

It should not be used. It is a [meta tag](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/) that gives no decent context to the question.

> And do we even need it?

No, we don't. If it were removed from those questions it would be deleted by the system.

Comment: I agree to burninate the tag. Should I create a new Meta question for this (like [Burninate flight](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3941/burninate-flight)) or is this one sufficient?

Comment: @Bianfable there's such a small number of them I would de-tag over a few days as to not swamp the homepage. I don't think we need to formalize this beyond this question.

Comment: 3 done, I'll do the other two tomorrow...